How to set a local custom domain name without a top level domain with dnsmasq?
Currently I'm following https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin.ng/wiki/Custom-domains-with-dnsmasq
on my router. I've created a dnsmasq.conf.add file with address=/g/192.168.0.96 in it.
I can access http://g/ on every device EXCEPT windows machines. Searching around, the only solutions I've found are manually configuring each windows device, which I want to avoid (e.g. adding suffix or editing hosts file).
Note that http://g./ does redirect on windows (which is the same as configuring the suffix).
I want a solution that "just works" for any device on the network trying to get to http://g/.

There is a difference between the guide you're following and what you've done - perhaps the fact that your "domain" has no . in it makes the difference with windows machines

Your domain itself is the top-level domain here. Browsers do not like to visit top-level domains; they have been coded with the assumption that a legitimate TLD will never have address records (used to be a rarity and I believe ICANN now forbids that outright). You most likely cannot change this behavior externally.
Instead, define a normal domain name (with 2+ components), then set up your DHCP server to advertise a "domain search suffix" to tell clients what to append after single-word names.
For example, you could define address=/g.example.corp/ as the website, then publish example.com as the Domain Search Suffix via DHCP, and browsers visiting http://g/ – or any other software for that matter – will automatically visit g.example.com due to the OS automatically appending the search suffix. This feature is widely supported.
(The other reason browsers don't want to visit TLDs is because the Domain Search Suffix mechanism has a higher priority! It makes sense when you think about it – names without a domain are "local", so it's the local network that defines where they are, rather than the very-global TLDs being responsible for that.)

To clarify what I did

add address=g.pickle.lan/192.168.0.96 to dnsmasq.conf.add
change the Domain Name on my router to pickle.lan
change the website's URL to http://g.pickle.lan
ipconfig /flushdns on all windows machines

